# JS: why use Symbols if they are not accessible?

Tags: javascript

I don't really understand the purpose of Symbols if they can't be accessed.  I know you can create one with a key as follows using `for` and then retrieve it with `keyFor`.

```
let keySymbol = Symbol.for("XXX");

console.log(Symbol.keyFor(keySymbol) // "XXX";
```

But when it comes to actually using them, what is the purpose of the example below?

```
let obj = {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 44,
}
obj[Symbol()] = false;
```

`console.log(obj)` doesn't have the symbol field and iterating through the object doesn't have it either so what purpose does it serve if you can't access it or read from it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol gives a good explanation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at this, is by changing your example a bit:

```
const mySymbol = Symbol();
obj[mySymbol] = false;
```

Because you still have access to `mySymbol`, you can still get access to this property. And because nobody can ever create it from scratch, nobody can accidentally overwrite it or access it *unless* they have access to `mySymbol`.

Comment: is one way to look at it that using them in an Object hide/protects its key name so that you can't overwrite it unless you know the variable assigned to the Symbol?

Comment: Yeah that's more or less what I tried to say.